# CloudWatch Monitoring and Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using various AWS services (Lambda, Glue, S3, Redshift, EC2) for ETL processing. I am trying to create a 'log ETL flow' to have monitoring and notifications sent out (email or otherwise) when a step fails in the process.

I have checked that each service I am using has metrics being logged in CloudWatch. I am now trying to figure out a smart way of processing this data in order to send out notifications when a step fails and/or have a central monitoring of the entire flow.

Are there any best practices or examples of this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the perfect case for the [CloudWatch Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html).

> You can create a CloudWatch alarm that watches a single CloudWatch metric or the result of a math expression based on CloudWatch metrics. The alarm performs one or more actions based on the value of the metric or expression relative to a threshold over a number of time periods. The action can be an Amazon EC2 action, an Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling action, or a notification sent to an Amazon SNS topic.

You can create a chain CloudWatch Alarm -> [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/?nc1=h_ls&whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc)

You can either use SNS to notify users via [SMS or Push Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-user-notifications.html).
Or you can do one step more SNS -> [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) to deliver emails.

Comment: I am looking to send logs from all services used to Redshift, so I can make a dashboard ontop of that data. Would it be any AWS service CloudWatch logs -> SNS -> Kinesis / Firehose -> Redshift in this case? Then I can apply business logic to the SNS if I need to send emails and use SES. Ideally I want a central monitoring hence the logs in a centralised place.

Comment: @charlesperry pretty much. You can also subscribe Firehose to CloudWatch directly, without SNS if you don't need SES. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample)